# What are some good books on problem solving for geometry upto a little higher than high school level

Tags: geometry

I feel I need to strengthen my geometry to an advanced level up to the introductory college level. Any suggestions for problem books.

Comment: Excursion in mathematics by mr modak is good

Comment: If you are looking for Olympiad Geometry, EGMO from Evan Chen is the best source I can recommend

Comment: ["Problem solving strategies" by Engel](http://gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc.skole.hr/upload/gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc/multistatic/748/Problem-Solving_Strategies_Engel.pdf)